# How do I Add FXM to the Login Form for Forefront Threat Management Gateway?

Tags: fxm

We have a TMG ( Forefront Threat Management Gateway ) Login form and we need to Add FXM to that Login Form. The intention of this is to enable Sitecore editors to embed Sitecore content to the place holders of the Login form.

I have added the Beacon script to the Login form but when I try to connect it through Experience Editor **I get the following error:**

```
Could not validate beacon script - The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized*.
```

The beacon script is placed in the login page itself so, theoretically no need to login to the site to read the beacon so I'm worried about this error and clueless.

**Note:** TMG is a secure web Gateway where we can provide Authentications to the sites by using login forms.

`Sitecore Version 8.1`

Comment: Does the beacon script work fine in any other hosted application. What does the http request to sitecore for beacon.js return ? 401 error ?